# Best way to find a shortest path between two nodes in Tinkerpop 3.1

Tags: shortest-path, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I know this was asked several time but I haven't found any reference regarding the last version of Tinkerpop (3.1), featuring many new useful functions we can use in our traversals.

Let's say I have to find **a** shortest path between nodes 3 and 4. 
Is this traversal sound?

```
g.V(3).repeat(out()).until(id().is(4).and().simplePath()).path().limit(1)
```

Here I'm assuming that when I'm looping a BFS search is executed (thus, the first result is the shortest path) as [it seems that this was the case with the `loop()` function](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/EOHO8ghPYP0).

Additionally, is there any way to include a previously bound variable (by using an `as` step) in the `until` step? 
More precisely, I'm trying to select two nodes during the traversal, and then finding the shortest path between them, for example,

```
g.V().match(
__as('e0').out('Feedbacks').as('e1'),
__as('e0').repeat(out('Meets')).until(<I reach e1>).path().<get_length>.as('len')
).select('e0', 'e1', 'len')
```

Finally, as can be seen from the previous traversal, it's not clear to me how I can get the length of the shortest path.
Using something like

```
g.V(3).repeat(out()).until(id().is(4).and().simplePath()).path().size()
```

returns the size of the result (number of rows returned), while

```
g.V(3).repeat(out()).until(id().is(4).and().simplePath()).path().by(__size())
```

returns an error.

Here is the graph I'm experimenting with, should anybody want to play a bit.

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
e0 = graph.addVertex(T.id, 0, label, "User", "name", "e0")
e1 = graph.addVertex(T.id, 1, label, "User", "name", "e1")
e2 = graph.addVertex(T.id, 2, label, "User", "name", "e2")
e3 = graph.addVertex(T.id, 3, label, "User", "name", "e3")
e4 = graph.addVertex(T.id, 4, label, "User", "name", "e4")
e0.addEdge("Feedbacks", e2)
e0.addEdge("Meets", e1)
e2.addEdge("Feedbacks", e4)
e2.addEdge("Meets", e4)
e3.addEdge("Feedbacks", e0)
e3.addEdge("Meets", e2)
e4.addEdge("Feedbacks", e0)
g = graph.traversal()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a slightly shorter variant for your shortest path query:

```
g.V(3).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasId(4)).path().limit(1)
```

Your assumption, that the first path is always the shortest path, is correct.
To get the path lengths, you can use `count(local)`:

```
g.V(3).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasId(4)).path().count(local)
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding your updated query, this one should solve the problem:

```
g.V().as("e0").out("Feedbacks").as("e1").select("e0").
      repeat(out("Meets")).until(where(eq("e1"))).path().
      map(union(count(local), constant(-2)).sum()).as("len").
      select("e0","e1","len")
```

I subtract 2 from the overall path length, because I think that you're only interested in the length of the path traversed by the `repeat()` block and the `out().select()` in the beginning should not be included. If that's not the case, then you can simply replace the 3rd line with `count(local).as("len").`.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Kuppitz. While you were writing your answer I modified the question. Will you have a bit of time to check the new request, that is, how i reference to a previously aliased node in the `until()` step?

Comment: Sorry for bothering again but.. I'm now trying to merge the results of the two questions by computing the length of the 'Meets' *undirected* (`both('Meets')`)shortest path connecting two vertices connected by a Feedbacks edge. It's not that trivial as I cannot use `simplePath()` inside the `repeat()` because of the `as('e0')`-`select('e0')` patterns, and I cannot select the first path with a `limit(1)` after `until()` since otherwise I loose solutions. Do you have any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: Make your life easier by splitting it into 2 separate queries - first iterate over all `e0` and `e1` and for each paar check if you can find a shortest path. Once a path is found, break out of the iteration.

Comment: To combine the queries, you would have to use a custom simple path check. Something like: `g.V().as("e0").out("Feedbacks").as("e1").select("e0").repeat(out("Meets").filter(match(__.as("a").path().as("p"), __.as("p").count(local).as("c"), __.as("p").union(dedup(local).count(local), constant(3)).sum().as("c")))).until(where(eq("e1"))).path().map(union(count(local), constant(-2)).sum()).as("len").select("e0","e1","len")` -- but IMO it's really not necessary ti make it so complicated.

Comment: Done! I've followed your first advice and I separated the traversal in two parts obtaining `w = []
for( fb in g.V().as('e0').out('Feedbacks').as('e1').select('e0', 'e1') ){ 
 w.add( g.V(fb.e0).
  repeat(both('Meets').simplePath()).
  until( where(id().is(fb.e1.id())) ).
  path().by('name').next() )
}
w`. Thanks again. I owe you a beer (or two :) ).

Comment: How to achieve this in python ?I tried g.V(3).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasId(4)).path().count(local), it doesnt give me the literal value.